# With pyodbc & SQL Server, how to insert multiple foreign keys in a table

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am able to insert a foreign key in a SQL table. However, after doing the same thing for 3 other tables, I will have to insert those 4 FK's in my fact table. I am asking now to know in advance if this is the way to go, database-model-wise.

Code to skip duplicate rows, insert columns and a FK RegionID:

```
cursor.execute((""" 
    IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT @address1client, @address2client, @cityClient
        INTERSECT
        SELECT address1client, address2client, cityClient
        FROM dbo.AddressClient)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.AddressClient (address1client, address2client, cityClient, RegionID)
        SELECT @address1client, @address2client, @cityClient, RegionID 
        FROM dbo.Region
        WHERE province=@province AND country=@country)
    END""")
```

My questions are:
Does a `BEGIN ... END` statement execute all at once? If the answer is yes, would the code below work? I ask, because there can at no point be FK_ID columns with null values.

```
...
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.Fact(product,saleTotal,saleDate) VALUES (@product, @saleTotal, @saleDate)

        INSERT INTO dbo.Fact (ClientAddressID)
        SELECT ClientAddressID
        FROM dbo.ClientAddress
        WHERE address1c=@address1c AND address2c=@address2c AND cityC=@cityC)

        INSERT INTO dbo.Fact (SupplierAddressID)
        SELECT SupplierAddressID
        FROM dbo.SupplierAddress
        WHERE address1s=@address1s AND address2s=@address2s AND cityS=@cityS)

        INSERT INTO dbo.Fact (DetailID)
        SELECT DetailID
        FROM dbo.Detail
        WHERE categoryNum=@categoryNum AND type=@type AND nature=@nature)
    END""")
```

2- If a `BEGIN ... END` statement doesn't execute all at once, how do I go about inserting multiple FK's in a table?

Comment: `Begin/End` does **not** happen all at once... Each insert statement happens individually.

Comment: You could do this with subqueries, or with setting local variables from a query. But if you are anyway inserting into those tables in the same procedure, save `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to a local variable after each insert, and use those variables to do the final insert into `Fact`